# windows batch: echo a multi-line variable with special characters (JiraRelease Notes from jenkins)

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, echo, jira

I am using the JiraPlugin in Jenkins to produe a ReleaseNotes and my build job in Jenkins uses batch files.

In the executed batch file, when I just issue a `set`, I can see that the varibale exists with the Jira Release notes. But it is multi-line and starts with a `#` character.

my goal is to do a
`echo %RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS% > ReleaseNotes.txt`

but that never works. I tried using `!!` instead of `%%` around the variable but that also does not work. I get `ECHO is off.` when I try to echo the variable.
Again, `set` does show it with the correct content:

```
RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS=# New Feature
 - [XXXX-3525] Blahblahblah
 - [XXXX-3268] Blahblahblah
 - [XXXX-3119] Blahblahblah
# UNKNOWN
 - [XXXX-3545] [security] Blahblahblah
...
```

Jenkins runs on a Windows 7 Server.
This is specific to windows Batch (cmd.exe) since simply piping the variable to a file works when the Jenkins runs on a Linux environment.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: so `# New Feature- [XXXX-3525] Blahblahblah- [XXXX-3268] Blahblahblah- [XXXX-3119] Blahblahblah` should be one variable? Are you getting the info from a file or through a command?

Comment: The variable is filled by the JiraPlugin from Jenkins. Its a Java class that uses a HashMap and writes that to the environment.
But the answer from @Giulio-vian works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SET RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS > ReleaseNotes.txt
```

instead of `echo`.

Comment: that does it. Thank you so much

Comment: The original OP code was only attempting to display the value, while this displays the variable name, followed by =, followed by the value. Also, this techinque will display all variables that begin with `RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS`. For example, it would also display the value of `RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS_2`.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed expansion should work:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !RELEASE_NOTES_JENKINS!>releasenotes.txt
```

Comment: I tried that before and it did not work. Maybe due to the way the content of the variable?
The line endings are also \n not \r\n...

Comment: @TabascoEye - Content and line endings make no difference. If `set var` works, then `setlocal enable delayed expansion` followed by `echo !var!` must also work, as long as the setlocal and echo are in the same batch script (actual file on disk).