# How to Echo Multi-Line variable from Jenkins?

Tags: variables, jenkins, eol

Good Day!
Any advice is appreciated.

I have a Jenkins job that takes in a multi-line parameter like this.
[Build with parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTwKI.png)

Why is it that when i try to echo this value in an "Execute windows batch command"

```
echo %DEPLOYSET%
```

I will only see the first line being echoed, which is "LineOne"

How can i retrieve the rest of the lines? Or echo them? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hello. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You should be able to use "Delayed expansion"**

Example to echo and to echo to a file:

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion && echo !foo!

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion && echo !foo! > C:\foobar\test.txt

I found this from another SO post ([windows batch: echo a multi-line variable with special characters (JiraRelease Notes from jenkins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717777/windows-batch-echo-a-multi-line-variable-with-special-characters-jirarelease-n))